# Pyspark dataframe sum aggregation in groupby and const division

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

Assuming with have a dataframe like this:

```
 Day     Hour     Values
Monday    7        65      
Monday    8        66
Monday    9        66
Tuesday   7        68
Tuesday   9        68
Tuesday   10       58
```

I can group by day and hour and sum the values as following:

```
groupby('Day', 'Hour').agg(F.sum('Values').alias('Values'))
```

What if I want to perform, at the same time, a division of the sum with a custom const value?

The easy way is to do the following after the groupby:

```
df.withColumn('Values', F.col("Values")/constant)
```

Is there a better way as in combining this expression in the aggregation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it just in place:

```
df_origin.groupby('Day', 'Hour').agg((F.sum('Values') / constant).alias('Values'))
```

Comment: hmm that's what I thought but it doesn't give the same result

Comment: what do you mean? I get the same result in both cases